# React parent and child coordination, fault in my design: why I have an infinite re-render loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need some advice about communicating between tree components and why my solution create an infinite re-rendering loop.

- `ProductFilters`: the parent which holds the state of all its child and eventually exposing it using **onChange prop**. A component on top of it should know the state of all filters.

  - `ColorFilter`: a color chooser, notify the parent using **onChange prop**
  - `SizeFilter`: a size chooser and depends on the value of `ColorFilter` using the **color prop**, notify the parent using **onChange prop**

I've prepared a simple schema to illustrate this:

[image: Schema]

But there is a fault in this design, that is an infinite re-render loop. What I'm doing wrong and what I'm missing? What is the usual "way" to manage this common kind of situations?

[This is a pen](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-rerender-loop-k2ueim?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), the console show the infinite loop and browser could freeze.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SizeFilter } from './SizeFilter';
import { ColorFilter } from './ColorFilter';

export const ProductFilters = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [sizeFilterParams, setSizeFilterParams] = useState({ color: '' });

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange({
      ...sizeFilterParams,
    });
  }, [sizeFilterParams, onChange]);

  const handleFilterChange = (name, value) => {
    switch (name) {
      case 'color':
        setSizeFilterParams(prev => ({ ...prev, color: value }));

        break;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='p-4'>
      <ColorFilter onChange={v => handleFilterChange('color', v)} />
      <SizeFilter {...sizeFilterParams} onChange={v => handleFilterChange('color', v)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `SizeFilter` component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const options = {
  S: ['red', 'green'],
  M: ['green'],
  L: ['green'],
  XL: ['red', 'green', 'blue']
};

export const SizeFilter = ({ color, onChange }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(selected);
  }, [selected, onChange]);

  return <select value={selected} onChange={handleChange}>
    <option value=''>Choose size</option>
    {Object.keys(options).filter(k => !color || options[k].includes(color)).map(k =>
      <option key={k} value={k}>{k}</option>
    )}
  </select>;
};
```

And the `ColorFilter`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const ColorFilter = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(selected);
  }, [selected, onChange]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <select value={selected} onChange={handleChange}>
      <option value=''>Choose color</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sandbox you are rerendering the filter component everytime the "onChange" is triggered. In your childs you are having the useEffect on every onChange change, so you are calling the onChange in your child, which will change the onChange in your parent (cause of the rerender) which will calling the useEffect in the child and so on.

So replace this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    onChange(selected);
  }, [selected, onChange]);
```

with this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    onChange(selected);
  }, [selected]);
```

and the loop is gone. You want to call the onChange only when the selected value is changed.

Btw: your sandbox is setting the size value to the color value, which is wrong I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just removed useEffect from your specific function and add the change callback in handleChange will resolve the infinite loop re-rendering issues

Adding callback function as dependencies will always make the call to function which cause the re-rendering

```
const handleChange = e => {
    setSelected(e.target.value);
    onChange(e.target.value);
  };
```